# Помогите с идеей решения к задаче

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем привет, я решала такую задачу:

```
Ограничение времени: 1 с
Ограничение реального времени: 5 с
Ограничение памяти: 256 M

Вы любите яблоки и за сегодня хотите съесть x зеленых яблок 
и y красных. У вас в саду поспело уже aзеленых яблок сладостью 
p1, p2, …, pa и b красных яблок сладостью q1, q2, …, qb. А еще 
у вас растет c магических яблок сладостью r1, r2, …, rc, 
которые вы умеете превращать перед едой в красные или зеленые.
Понятное дело, что вы хотите съесть яблоки с наибольшей 
суммарной сладостью.
Найдите максимально возможную сумму сладости съеденных яблок, 
которая может быть достигнута при оптимальном превращении 
магических яблок.

Формат входных данных
В первой строке записано пять чисел 
x, y, a, b, c
(1≤x≤a≤10^5,1≤y≤b≤10^5,1≤c≤10^5).

Во второй строке записано a чисел pi
(1≤pi≤10^9) — сладость зеленых яблок

В третьей строке записано b чисел qi
(1≤qi≤10^9) — сладость красных яблок

В четвертой строке записано c чисел ri
(1≤ri≤10^9) — сладость магических яблок

Формат выходных данных
Выведите максимально возможную сумму сладости съеденных яблок.

Примеры
Входные данные
1 3 2 3 4
5 6
1 2 3
10 11 12 13
Выходные данные
46
Входные данные
1 1 2 2 1
10 4
5 6
1
Выходные данные
16
```

Но я не представляю идею для написания кода, помогите пожалуйста придумать идею для реализации(код не нужен), буду очень благодарна за помощь!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала сделай ввод всех данных.

Найди все максимальные x зелёных и y красных яблок.

Сделай из максимальных яблок общий массив.

Отсортируй массив с максимальными яблоками.

Отсортируй массив с магическими яблоками по убыванию.

Теперь если максимальное число из массива с магическими яблоками больше самого маленького числа массива с максимальными x и y яблоками, то меняешь на магическое яблоко.

И так продолжаешь делать пока максимальное число из массива с магическими яблоками больше самого маленького числа массива с максимальными x и y яблоками.

Потом идёшь опять по массиву x и y из складываешь числа.

Выводишь ответ.

Напиши, если что-то непонятно.

Удачи тебе с отбором =).

Сколько задач решила с отбора?

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за поддержку, решила 4 задачи

Comment: А какие задачи, если не секрет

Answer (score 0):

первая строка - ввод 5 чисел через map

вторая строка - массив из a чисел с попощью maxspleet

третья и четвертая - аналогично

сначала вычти натуральные яблоки из общего кол-ва

теперь умножай съеденое на сладкость

потом соедини нехватки яблок и умножь на сладкость магических

Answer (score 0):

Отсортируйте все яблоки, зеленые `G`, красные `R` и магические `M`

Возьмите `x` наибольших зеленых и `y` наибольших красных, сложите их в один список `RG`, опять же отсортированный.

(В принципе, полная сортировка первичных списков необязательна, можно и `heapq.nlargest` воспользоваться, но особо это роли не сыграет)

Теперь пройдите по списку `RG` вверх, а по списку `M` - вниз, пока значения не пересекутся или один из списков не кончится - пусть это будут индексы `iRG` и `jM`.

```
        v
5 7     8 9 13 15           RG
два элемента выкидываем 
      v
3 4 6 7     10 20             M
           два отсюда берём
```

Меньшие этой границы значения из `RG` заменятся на большие её значения из `M`, и результат - `sum(RG[iRG:])+sum(M[jM+1:])`

Вариант, как ESkri в комментариях предложил - объединить `x` наибольших зеленых, `y` наибольших красных, `min(c, x+y)` наибольших магических, и взять `x+y` наибольших значений из этой кучи (опять же можно `heapq.nlargest`)

Comment: сложновато!  можно проще: взять `x` наибольших зеленых, `y` наибольших красных и `x+y` наибольших магических, все перемешать и взять `x+y` наибольших.

Comment: @ESkri Я думал такое описать c тем же heapq.nlargest, но мне как раз показалось сложнее;)

Comment: вместо "min(c, x+y) наибольших магических" можно сказать: "все магические"